Can you loop a charge pump?
Is it possible, to charge two capacitors in parallel(eg. each two volts). Discharge them in series to a third capacitor(4 volts). Charge the first capacitor again with the initial voltage(2 volts). Connect that one with the third capacitor in series. Discharge the higher voltage to the second capacitor(6 volts). And just keep going(8, 10, 12,… volts)?

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier

Near total re-write:
Here's an experiment you can do at home. You can do it on a breadboard if you have the parts and the power supply, or you can simulate it with SPICE or, with similar software:

All three capacitors have the same value, $C_i$. The value doesn't really matter, but I'd use electrolytic caps with some tens of microfarads.
Set it up so that initially; the switch is open, and all three capacitors have been charged to 2V. The voltage at A is 4V, and the voltage at B is 2V. Then close the switch. After the transient settles down, what will be the voltage at A and B?*
The charge stored in a capacitor is $Q=CV$, where $C$ is the value of the capacitor, and $V$ is the voltage.
The two identical caps in series on the left behave like a cap with half the value, so the effective capacitance of the right hand branch before the switch is closed is $0.5C_i$, and the effective charge that they store is $Q_{left}=4\times{}0.5C_i$, or $2C_i$. The charge on the right hand side simply is $Q_{right}=2C_i$.
Upon closing the switch, the whole circuit acts like a single capacitor whose value is $C_e=1.5C_i$ because we can simply add capacitances in parallel. So, let's redistribute the total charge, $Q_t=Q_{left}+Q_{right}$ ($Q_t=4C_i$):
$$V=\frac{Q_t}{C_e}$$
$$V=\frac{4C_i}{1.5C_i}$$
$$V=\frac{4}{1.5}$$
$$V=2.666$$
So, after doing what you said:

charge two capacitors in parallel(eg. each two volts). Discharge them in series to a third capacitor(4 volts).

The voltage on the third capacitor will not be four volts. You only will have gained two thirds of a volt. Meanwhile, the other two capacitors will be down below 2V, but you can reconnect them to the power supply and charge them up to 2V again.
Now, repeat the experiment with 4.666V at A and 2V at B (Or, do it with 4V at A and 2.666V at B.) I'll let you do the math, but I think you're going to see diminishing returns. I'm pretty sure that the voltage that you can achieve after N steps will approach a finite, not very big limit.
You said, in a comment below, "I‘m thinking of something like a mechanical marx generator."
A Marx generator does not "loop." It doesn't just have three capacitors, it has as many capacitors as it has stages. That's an important difference between a Marx generator and your scheme. That's what allows the output voltage to grow without theoretical limit as you add more stages.

* Of course, after the switch is closed and the transient settles down, the voltages measured at A and B must be equal.

You circuit diagram shows two capacitors in series already. I‘m thinking of something like a mechanical marx generator. Charging in parallel and discharging in series. But discharging it in to another capacitor.

@Aaa, See my re-written answer, above.

That is quite simple if you just do it with a few wires by hand! Obviously you should take care not to discharge any of the capacitors by touching the non-insulated part of the wires with your hands. You could also make a circuit with a few mechanical switches to do it (but then you need to operate those switches by hand).
Of course the most convenient way is to use electronic switches, like MOSFETs, which is how it is actually done in many
[switched capacitor voltage converters], also called "charge pumps".

When you connect your 2 capacitors in series to the 3rd capacitor, the voltage is no longer 4V, because some charge is transfered to the 3rd capacitor (so as to equalize the voltages). How much charge is transfered depends on the ratio of the capacitances.
So you cannot ramp up the voltage as you imagined.
